# Generic FSM for game in C++?

Tags: c++, fsm

I was wondering if there's a way I could code some kind of "generic" FSM for a game with C++?.

My game has a component oriented design, so I use a FSM Component.

my Finite State Machine (FSM) Component, looks more or less this way.

```
class gecFSM : public gecBehaviour 
{

public:
    //Constructors
    gecFSM() { state = kEntityState_walk; }
    gecFSM(kEntityState s) { state = s; }

    //Interface
    void setRule(kEntityState initialState, int inputAction, kEntityState resultingState);
    void performAction(int action);

private:
    kEntityState fsmTable[MAX_STATES][MAX_ACTIONS];

};
```

I would love to hear your opinions/ideas or suggestions about how to make this FSM component, generic. With generic I mean:

1) Creating the fsmTable from an xml file is really easy, I mean it's just a bunch of integers that can be loaded to create an MAX_STATESxMAX_ACTION matrix.

```
void gecFSM::setRule(kEntityState initialState, int inputAction, kEntityState resultingState)
{
    fsmTable[initialState][inputAction] = resultingState;
}
```

2) But what about the "perform Action" method ?

```
void gecFSM::performAction(int action)
{
    switch( smTable[ ownerEntity->getState() ][ action ] )
    {
        case WALK:
            /*Walk action*/
        break;
        case STAND:
            /*Stand action*/
        break;
        case JUMP:
            /*Jump action*/
        break;
        case RUN:
            /*Run action*/
        break;
    }
}
```

What if I wanted to make the "actions" and the switch generic?

This in order to avoid creating a different FSM component class for each `GameEntity`? (`gecFSMZombie`, `gecFSMDryad`, `gecFSMBoss` etc ?). That would allow me to go "Data Driven" and construct my generic FSM's from files for example.

What do you people suggest?

Comment: Have you looked at the boost state machine library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Boost Statechart Library. (formerly known as boost::fsm)
It comes with a very nice photo camera example.